# React v0.14 Beta 1/v0.13.3 as npm Usability

Tags: reactjs

Since React does not render some HTML on the server properly and [has a nasty bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3824) I was forced to upgrade to a higher version via npm. Then I had the problem of having two independent copies of React in the browser. React tells me about the error: 'This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React'

This is my packaging code:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src(['app/main.js'])
        .pipe(browserify({
            debug: true,
            transform: ['reactify']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));

});
gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

Before upgrading I had no problem of having two reacts in the browser.

The packaging code has not changed. The first question is: What has the update to do with the problem and how do I solve it?

Thx much in advance!

Edit: Also tried it with browserify instead of gulp-browserify, but without luck. Just tried it with 13.3. [I had hope, that this bug had been fixed with that version](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3824), but that is not the case. Interestingly browserify works with that version. There are no two Reacts on the client with version 0.13.3, so apparently it *has* something to do with React. But there is this server side rendering bug in the most current 0.13.3

I am somewhat desperate. I chose React for isomorphic Javascript, but neither version do. Is React not ready for production at all or what am I doing wrong?